# Why is my C++ code with file output not working?

Tags: c++, fstream, norton

I didn't got any errors, but my C++ code is still not working. It's really simple:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;

    ofstream fout("char.out");
    ifstream fin("char.in");

    fin >> a;
    fout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

char.in after running:

```
uiui
```

char.out after running:

Did I missed anything simple in my code?

*P. S. : I got Norton Antivirus and my project folder is missed from AutoCheck.*

Comment: Where is your `"char.out"` relative to executable?

Comment: *"Did I missed anything"* - some remote sense of IO validation would certainly be a good place to start. You never  either file for open-success. `if (fin.is_open())` at a bare minimum must be true, or anything thereafter is pointless.

Comment: Try `if (fin >> a) cout << "Read ok\n"; else cout << "Read failed\n";`

Comment: uhhhhh... I got `Read failed`

Comment: That's because your open failed. Always, always check when you open a file that it succeeded. It's almost the first rule of programming.

Comment: `if (!fin.is_open()) { perror("char.in"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` immediately after the construction of `fin` is strongly encouraged.

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein in the same folder

Comment: And what is the current directory when the executable runs?

Comment: @me1234 Whether it in the same folder is not relevant. What matters is whether it's in the current working directory.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

in fact for reading and writing you should open and close file but you didn't close.

Also you have two files where you have done writing from one file and reading from another file, I wonder how you expect to get the correct output.

this is how it should be :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;

    ofstream fout("char.out");
    
   //  check if file is created
   if(fout.is_open()){
   //  do writing in file
  
   }
    else 
     cout << "can not open file\n";

    fout.close();

//-----------reading the file----------



    // use the same file
    ifstream fin("char.out");

    if(fun.is_open()){
     // do reading from file
     std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
     else
      cout << "can not open file\n";
     
     fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And if you want to add a line of text to the end of the file, you must add:

```
ofstream fout("filename" , ios::app);
```

Comment: An `fstream` implements [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). The object closes the file in the destructor. The OP tries to read from one (`char.in`) file write into a different file (`char.out`).

Comment: And when will the destructor be called?

Comment: At the end of the lifetime of the object. In this case, at the end of the program.

Comment: I know thet , But if you look at the question you can see that he wants to create a file, save to the file and open it again and read it before the program finishes, also if the file is not closed the data is not saved in it, so he has to manually close the file  before program end.

Comment: I see two different files in the code in the question `ofstream fout("char.out"); ifstream fin("char.in");`

Comment: exactly that's one of the problems.

Comment: The goal of the code is to copy the content from `char.in` to `char.out`. The OP has a file with content and asks why the other file is empty.